# Complexity of this related for loops?

Tags: loops, for-loop, time-complexity

What is the complexity of this code?

```
for i in range(0,n):
    for k in range(i,n):
        print("hello")
        k /= 4
    i += i*2.02
```

Comment: You should be able to at least write down how many steps the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and last iterations through the inner loop take and form a guess as to the complexity. After that it becomes a math problem that we'll be glad to help with.